Canvas API - upload_to_submission succeeds, but there is nu submission
I'm an instructor, and I created an assignment which requires file submission. I want to upload a submission file for a student using Canvas API.
from canvasapi import Canvas

canvas = Canvas('https://canvas.[my university].edu', canvas_api_key)
course = canvas.get_course(args.course_id)
assignment = course.get_assignment(args.assignment_id)
user = course.get_user(netid, "sis_user_id")
res = assignment.upload_to_submission(file_path, user)
print(res)

The first element in res is True, which, according to the docs, means that the upload succeeded. I also checked the url field in the JSON output, and following the url indeed shows the uploaded file.
So the call succeeds, except that I don't see the uploaded file on Canvas. So, the student still doesn't have a submission.
How to fix that? Publishing the assignment doesn't help.
